# How can i put a button on an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to put a button "add" on photos. Like in this photo [image]

```
<div class="row">
        <div th:each="photo : ${photos}" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img th:src="${photo.path}" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>
                        <button th:class=".add-to-cart"
                            th:onclick="'addPhotoToOrder(' + ${photo.id} + ')'"
                            type="button" class="btn btn-primary" th:text="#{message.add}"></button>
                    </p>
```

But this is my result:
[image]

Comment: easier with a background image

Comment: Inspect CSS from your source website and use the same for your purpose. Its most likely doing on hover tricks and possibly psuedo attributes or just hidden div to layer on top

Comment: Just overlay the button on top of an image?

Comment: check this link https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-place-a-button-on-image-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can try these ways (flex and absolute positioning):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.btn-container button {
  height: 15px;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-container2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.btn-container2 button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<div class="container2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
  <div class="btn-container2">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FLEX PROs**

Actually **flex** is better, because it puts it in the center (exactly), while with **absolute** positioning the button container's top is put in the center vertically (so not its middle point) - you can meddle with that (like `top: calc(50% - 7.5px);` (in the case if the button is 15px high), or something like that, but **flex** solves it out of the box.

**FLEX CONs**

Flexbox can still cause problems in different browsers (like adding a 1px "border", or other problems). This may cause your layout to change unexpectedly.

Comment: I used your solution but the button is under the photo not over it

Comment: Then there's something has an effect on this CSS. If you can **provide a JSFiddle of your code that's supposed to be working**, then it can be solved - otherwise it's only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

use absolute position

```
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    right:auto;
    bottom:auto;
    left:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these HTML and CSS code to add a button on an image.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="photo-1556924784-f02bd5b5b094.jpg">
        <button class="btn">Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }

.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

.container .btn:hover {
   background-color: Red;
  }
```

Comment: i used your solution but the button is under the photo not over it